# Is $y = |\ln x| $ differentiable at $x = 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Is $y = |\ln x| $ differentiable at $x = 1$?

Derivative of $|\ln x|$ is $\frac{|\ln x|}{x\ln x}$ but can't prove why it is not differentiable  at the given point.

Comment: Just sketch the graph of $|\ln x|$ around $x=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here our function isn't too complex, so let's just look at the definition of the derivative and compare the two one-sided limits.

Coming from the right, we have $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{|\ln x| - |\ln 1|}{x - 1}.$ For any $x > 1,$ the monotonicity of $\ln x$ over that domain gives us $\ln(x) > 0,$ so we can simplify this as $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\ln x}{x - 1},$ which is simply the derivative of $\ln x$ at $x = 1,$ which is $\frac{1}{1} = 1.$

Now consider what happens when we come from the left, giving us $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{|\ln x| - |\ln 1|}{x - 1}.$ Now for $0 < x < 1$ we similarly have $\ln x < 0,$ so this simplifies to $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{-\ln x}{x - 1}.$ By the linearity of limits this is the negative of what we had before, so the left-handed limit is $-1 \neq 1.$ The two one-sided limits do not agree, so the limit does not exist and the function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln x$$ is growing, with a nonzero derivative at $x=1$, where it crosses the axis. Hence after taking the absolute value, the slope will change sign at $x=1$, creating a discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If it were differentiable at $1$, the limit of the rate of variation of $y$ between $1$ and $x$ should be the same from the left and from the right.